# How to removing "mirror copy" rows in a pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subset

I have the following pandas DataFrame has "mirror copy" rows between A-B-E and C-D-F:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 47, 27], [5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 40], [9, 10, 11, 12, 45, 33], 
    [3, 4, 1, 2, 27, 47], [7, 8, 5, 6, 40, 21], [11, 12, 9, 10, 33, 45]]), 
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

print(df1)

##     A   B   C   D   E   F
## 0   1   2   3   4  47  27
## 1   5   6   7   8  21  40
## 2   9  10  11  12  45  33
## 3   3   4   1   2  27  47
## 4   7   8   5   6  40  21
## 5  11  12   9  10  33  45
```

By "mirror copies", I mean the following: if you look at rows 3, 4, 5, these are "mirror copies" of rows 0, 1, 2. Columns A and B in rows 0, 1, 2 are columns C and D in rows 3, 4, 5.

For example, in row 0, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] is [1, 2, 3, 4]. In row 3, ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'] is [3, 4, 1, 2].

This is true with columns E and F as well---E values in rows 0, 1, 2 are the F values in rows 3, 4, 5.

I would like to remove these "mirror copy" rows and only leave the "unique" pairs. The correct output above should be either:

```
##     A   B   C   D   E   F
## 0   1   2   3   4  47  27
## 1   5   6   7   8  21  40
## 2   9  10  11  12  45  33
```

or

```
##     A   B   C   D   E   F
## 0   3   4   1   2  27  47
## 1   7   8   5   6  40  21
## 2  11  12   9  10  33  45
```

but not both---only one copy of the rows.

I don't know how to subset a pandas DataFrame in order to remove these sorts of rows. How could one do this in an algorithmically efficient (without an explosion of memory) way?

My first idea is wrong, as it only checks per row:

```
df1 = df1[~((df1.A == df1.C) & (df1.B == df1.D) & (df1.E == df1.F))]
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Is "mirror copy" limited to certain columns?  Or can any rearrangement of values in one row constitute a mirror copy?

Comment: @piRSquared It's only related to [A, B, E] and [C, D, F]. The mirror copies of A only exist in C, B only in D, E only in F. I hope this makes sense---if not, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
from collections import Counter

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


def key(x):
    return frozenset(Counter(x).items())


df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 47, 27], [5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 40], [9, 10, 11, 12, 45, 33],
                            [3, 4, 1, 2, 27, 47], [7, 8, 5, 6, 40, 21], [11, 12, 9, 10, 33, 45]]),
                  columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])

keys = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']].apply(key, axis=1)
mask = keys.duplicated(keep='last')

print(df[mask])
```

**Output**

```
   A   B   C   D   E   F
0  1   2   3   4  47  27
1  5   6   7   8  21  40
2  9  10  11  12  45  33
```

The idea is to create a `keys` column (Series) that will have the same value on those rows that are mirror of each other.

This:

```
def key(x):
    return frozenset(Counter(x).items())


keys = df[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']].apply(key, axis=1)
```

creates the `keys` column, then this marks the duplicated values:

```
mask = keys.duplicated(keep='last')
```

You can also use the key suggested by @piRSquared:

```
def key(x): 
    a, b, c, d, e, f = x
    return tuple(map(frozenset, [(a, c), (b, d), (e, f)]))
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer! This is helpful. Just so I can learn (and not spam SO), could you explain a bit more what you are doing? That would be helpful for me I think.

Comment: I don't believe you need `Counter`

Comment: @piRSquared I believe you need Counter to keep the multiplicity of the elements. Otherwise [1, 1, 2] is going to be equals to [2, 2, 1].

Comment: With the specific column requirements, I'd do something like `def key(x): a, b, c, d, e, f = x; return tuple(map(frozenset, [(a, c), (b, d), (e, f)]))`

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thank you for the help! Yes, this appears to work; I've checked if the rows are in different order as well.

Comment: Forgive me, I edited my comment.  The first `frozenset` should be a `tuple`

Comment: @piRSquared Out of curiosity, is there a performance difference between using Counter and not? Or would this be a matter solely of clean/simple code? Thank you both again! Just trying to learn here :)

Comment: @EB2127 I still feel as if the use of `frozenset` across the whole row is incorrect.  Assume you swapped the values of `2` and `27` in columns `'D'` and `'E'` in row `3` (fourth row).  That row should no longer be considered a "mirror copy" as per my understanding of what you defined.  However, if I'm wrong in my understanding, then `Counter` becomes necessary to distinguish between one instance of a value and two instances of a value.  If I'm right in my understanding, then the `key` provided by DanielMesejo won't work in general and you should replace that function with the one I suggested.

Comment: @piRSquared "That row should no longer be considered a "mirror copy" as per my understanding of what you defined." Yes, that's correct---such a row is not a mirror copy. To remove any ambiguity, could you offer such a solution for future readers? Following comments several months/years later gets confusing.

I also think working through a counter example is useful for educational purposes.

And I'm still a bit confused about the discussion of `Counter`...I apologize

Comment: @piRSquared I tried using your key for the values with swapped `D` and `E`. I think there's a mistake, as the key you provided removes both rows. Try `df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4, 47, 27], [5, 6, 7, 8, 21, 40], [9, 10, 11, 12, 45, 33], [3, 4, 1, 27, 2, 47], [7, 8, 5, 6, 40, 21], [11, 12, 9, 10, 33, 45]]), 
    columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])`

Comment: @DanielMesejo Please note issue with the key above as well. Apologies I didn't notice this yesterday

Comment: @EB2127 Is there an issue or not? Sorry to ask, did not understood "not issue"?

Comment: @DanielMesejo Sorry, there's a spelling error. "Please note" :)

There are two issues/problems. With your function `key`, if values D and E are swapped in row 3, then that row is not a mirror copy---it's still removed though as if it is a mirror copy. 

The problem with piRSquared's solution is that if the values in row 3 are swapped, his key function removes both rows.

Comment: The solution is there somewhere.  @DanielMesejo has the correct framework.  It's just nailing down the `key`

Comment: @piRSquared I think your solution makes sense if one does `df1[~mask]`. `df1[mask]` keeps the "mirror copies", but I'm trying to remove them.

I think that's the solution---please let me know if that makes sense to you both.